# POST 429 Error when trying to place more than 20 images into post at once

Tags: customization, images, ajax, wp-admin, admin

I’ve come across a bug that I can’t seem to fix and it seems to be on multiple WP sites that I manage / own.

The issue:
When placing multiple images into a wordpress post it spits out “VM392:1 POST https://www.laserlines.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 429″

I’ve tried to do some research to see if this is a common problem but I can’t find anything. I’ve also discovered that it only happens when trying to upload more than 20 images at once. At 20 or below it’ll accept it and place it into the post…

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a php ini directive called 'max_file_uploads', which (as it happens) defaults to 20. So, this is the number of files php will allow you to upload in one go. If you can edit the php ini yourself, then you can probably add or update this value. If not, then your server team will need to do it.

Comment: The issue unfortunately isn't when uploading the images. The images are already on the server but when selecting them to put them into the post or slider if I have more than 20 selected the Add Images button fades (after click) and the media library pop up stays open. The console then spits out a bunch of 429 errors.

Comment: It is a bit of a coincidence that the max_file_uploads defaults to 20 and you have the issue when adding 20 images to your slider though. Maybe the same logic is shared somewhere. Is it worth increasing the max_file_uploads temporarily just to see if it affects things?